# terraform import google computer security policy Error reading SecurityPolic Error reading SecurityPolicy googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to import an existing security policy using

```
terraform import google_compute_security_policy.testpolicy lunar-11111/testsecuritypolicy
```

I have this defined in my terraform file:

```
resource "google_compute_security_policy" "testpolicy" {
  name = "testsecuritypolicy"
}
```

However, this is error I get:

```
google_compute_security_policy.testpolicy: Importing from ID "lunar-111111/testsecuritypolicy"...
google_compute_security_policy.testpolicy: Import complete!
  Imported google_compute_security_policy
google_compute_security_policy.testpolicy: Refreshing state... [id=lunar-111111/testsecuritypolicy]

Error: Error reading SecurityPolicy "lunar-111111/testsecuritypolicy":
googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value 'lunar-111111/testsecuritypolicy'.
Values must match the following regular expression:
'[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?|[1-9][0-9]{0,19}', invalidParameter
```

I tried the other import formats listed in https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_security_policy.html with the same error.

I am able to create a new security policy using terraform.
Am I missing some configuration?  Any help would be appreciated.

The project name was changed in the above command and error result.

```
terraform -version
Terraform v0.12.2
+ provider.google v2.9.0
+ provider.random v2.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow GCP documentations on [configuring cloud armor security](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies) policies and [REST resources: securityPolicies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/securityPolicies).

To understand the error on regular expressions, I found [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Ba-z%5D%28%3F%3A%5B-a-z0-9%5D%7B0%2C61%7D%5Ba-z0-9%5D%29%3F%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B0%2C19%7D) that can explain details about the syntax and description.